# On a triple integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

Let $M$ be the interesection of the elliptic cylinder $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\leqslant1$ and the ellipsoid

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \leqslant 1 \;\; a>0,\,b>0,\,c>0$$

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ evaluate the integrals

$$I_n=\displaystyle\mathop{\iiint}\limits_{M}\big(a^2b^2-b^2x^2-a^2y^2\big)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\,{\rm{d}}(x,y,z)$$

**Question:**

What is the intersection $M$? I can see the substitution but I am having a hard time finding $M$.

Comment: Isn't the ellipsoid completely contained in the cylinder by virtue of $z^2/c\geq0$?

Comment: Yes, it is as I had seen it in the Geogebra dynamic drawing while playing around..

Comment: If you already knew that, why are you asking what $M$ is?

Comment: I somehow got confused with the question... !! and because I don't trust myself on that kind of things that is why I ask .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that the ellipsoid is contained into the elliptic cylinder:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \leqslant 1\implies \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}\leqslant 1.$$
Therefore, after the substitution $X:=x/a$, $Y:=y/b$ and $Z:=z/c$ we have that
$$I_n=(ab)^{2n-1}abc\mathop{\iiint}\limits_{{X^2+Y^2+Z^2\leq 1}}\big(1-X^2-Y^2\big)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\,dXdYdZ.$$

Comment: OK.. I got the self-confidence I needed to go on. Thank you both.

Comment: Thank you for the further hint. I can go on from here.